# Finding Palidrome from a permutation in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation, palindrome

I have a string, I need to find out `palindromic sub-string of length 4`( `all` `4 indexes` sub-strings), in which the indexes should be in `ascending order (index1<index2<index3<index4)`.
My code is working fine for small string like `mystr`. But when it comes to large string it takes long time.

```
   from itertools import permutations
    #Mystr
    mystr = "kkkkkkz" #"ghhggh"
    #Another Mystr
    #mystr = "kkkkkkzsdfsfdkjdbdsjfjsadyusagdsadnkasdmkofhduyhfbdhfnsklfsjdhbshjvncjkmkslfhisduhfsdkadkaopiuqegyegrebkjenlendelufhdysgfdjlkajuadgfyadbldjudigducbdj"
    l = len(mystr)
    mylist = permutations(range(l), 4)
    cnt = 0
    for i in filter(lambda i: i[0] < i[1] < i[2] < i[3] and (mystr[i[0]] + mystr[i[1]] + mystr[i[2]] + mystr[i[3]] == mystr[i[3]] + mystr[i[2]] + mystr[i[1]] + mystr[i[0]]), mylist):
        #print(i)
        cnt += 1
    print(cnt) # Number of palindromes found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick with the basic structure of your current algorithm, a few ways to speed it up would be to use `combinations` instead of the `permutations`, which will return an iterable in sorted order. This means you don't need to check that the indexes are in ascending order.  Secondly you can speed up the bit that checks for a palindrome by simply checking to see if the first two characters are identical to the last two characters reversed (instead of comparing the whole thing against its reversed self).

```
from itertools import combinations
mystr = "kkkkkkzsdfsfdkjdbdsjfjsadyusagdsadnkasdmkofhduyhfbdhfnsklfsjdhbshjvncjkmkslfhisduhfsdkadkaopiuqegyegrebkjenlendelufhdysgfdjlkajuadgfyadbldjudigducbdj"
cnt = 0 
for m in combinations(mystr, 4):
    if m[:2] == m[:1:-1]: cnt += 1
print cnt
```

Or if you want to simplify that last bit to a one-liner:

```
print len([m for m in combinations(mystr, 4) if m[:2] == m[:1:-1]])
```

I didn't do a real time test on this but on my system this method takes about 6.3 seconds to run (with your really long string) which is significantly faster than your method.

Comment: Can I speedup in some other way? Just give me a hint I will try it.

Comment: I'd recommend reading [this](https://books.google.ca/books?id=9NdohJXtIyYC&lpg=PP1&ots=llc90BNZHd&dq=rytter+jewels+o&pg=PA111&redir_esc=y&hl=en#v=onepage&q&f=false) for a good analysis of some algorithms that might help you out.  Or you can find a good tutorial on algorithms for finding the longest palindrome [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-12-longest-palindromic-subsequence/) which you might be able to adapt for your case. You're using a pretty brute force method at the moment so improving your algorithm is your best bet.

Comment: you can further save some milliseconds by m == m[::-1]
saves some computation on Left Hand Side

Comment: Good point @be_good_do_good. Also if you use the one-liner above its going to create a pretty big list object so if you want to save on memory you can use `sum(1 for m in combinations(mystr, 4) if m == m[::-1])` instead